# jQuery .get not working on new server

Tags: jquery, get

Im using jQuery `.get` to pull in and then parse an xml file. It was working fine on my test environment, but when moved to production server its not working. Is there anything wrong with my code that would cause this?

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "RSS/NinjaTraderRSS.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseXml
          });

          function parseXml(xml)
            {
              $(xml).find('item').each(function() {
                    var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                    var page  = $(this).find('link').text();
                    var desc  = $(this).find('description').text();
                    $('#ticker').append($('<li>', '<a href={text: page}>', {text: title}, {text: desc}));
                    //$('#ticker').append($('<li><a href="' + page + '">' + title + '</a>' + '&nbsp;' + '-' + '&nbsp;' + desc + '</li>'));
                });
                $('ul#ticker').newsTicker();
            }
        });
```

When i view the net in firebug it is returning a 200 OK for the xml, but when i inspect the element its not appending to the ul.

Im using the jquery "newsTicker" plug in to make them cycle through. Is there a way to do this without the plug in? Im in a bad spot here...help is very much appreciated.
thx

Comment: What's happening differently between the two environments? Are you getting the same XML? Are you perhaps getting a 404 on one or some of the scripts included on the page?

Comment: @Michael - nothing is happening differently. When i view the net in firebug it is returning a 200 OK, but when i inspect the element its not appending to the ul.

Comment: could you add the HTTP headers (request & response) in your question?

Comment: headers are huge and i can't format them here in the comments. site is at http://www.ninjatrader.com

Comment: Is the test environment publicly available?

Comment: It's not test anymore, its just not working. yes you can view it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the following in your script:

```
$('#ticker').append($('<li>', '<a href={text: page}>', {text: title}, {text: desc}));
//$('#ticker').append($('<li><a href="' + page + '">' + title + '</a>' + '&nbsp;' + '-' + '&nbsp;' + desc + '</li>'));
```

Commenting out the first line instead of the second fixes the problem.

Comment: You didn't change it... I'm still seeing the same thing as before.

Comment: thank you. I mistakenly commented out the same line again. Now its correct and fixed. It wasn't able to parse it with above I believe? is that correct? Michael, thank you!

Comment: In the line above you are calling the jquery base function (the selector) with options it's not expecting and it gets tripped up. The errors it displayed in the console were very non-illustrative of the actual problem going on.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the MIME type is set correctly (`text/xml`) on the document being returned?

Comment: here is what I have in the xml file <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<rss version="2.0">

Comment: The mime type is sent in the headers. In this case, it's `Content-Type application/xml`.

Comment: so I need to change the header from application/xml to text/xml...? is this a server thing, it worked before...